# Magento 2: Rest API "PUT" method Customer is not updated

Tags: rest-api, magento2.3.0, customer-update

Rest API for updating customer `PUT` method not working. Every time creating new customer.

> Method: PUT
>
> Request URL: http://localhost/magento/rest/en/V1/customers/55

**Body:**

```
{
   "customer": {
     "email": "test@gmail.com",
     "firstname": "firstname new",
     "lastname":  "lastname new",
     "website_id": 1
   }
}
```

Also when pass the customer Email Id then response is throwing below error.

**Response:**

```
{
    "message": "A customer with the same email address already exists in an associated website."
}
```

`Github Issue URL:` https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24625

Comment: Try V1/customers/me with customer token in authorisation header.

Comment: Did you get solution as Ramkishan mentioned or?

Comment: What params need to be passed in request?

Comment: @AnkitaPatel Not yet.

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar Already try but not working.

Comment: it's not error it's exactly what it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Request URL: http://localhost/magento/rest/en/V1/customers/55

**Body :**

```
{
   "customer": {
     "id":55,
     "email": "test@gmail.com",
     "firstname": "firstname new",
     "lastname":  "lastname new",
     "website_id": 1
   }
}
```

Add here **ID** field to update existing customer, also add all required fiels in payload.